# MongoDB Syntax Error Unexpected Token

Tags: mongodb, syntax

I am new to MongoDB. I am just following tutorialspoint.com for learning mongoDB.

I executed these two commands exactly as given :

```
db.test.save( { a: 1 } )
db.test.find(){ "_id" : ObjectId(5879b0f65a56a454), "a" : 1 }
```

I am getting error SyntaxError: Unexpected Token {

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you dont want to help its fine, there are thousands others who are willing to help.

Comment: Ask yourself who did better out of this? The person who corrected your syntax or you heeding my comment and deleting before someone answered and correcting this yourself when you only received downvotes for your lack of effort. So no need to be snide with me when I actually tried to help you help yourself.

Comment: very trivial. lacks effort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your query:

```
 test.find() { "_id" : ObjectId(5879b0f65a56a454), "a" : 1 }
```

Correct query:

```
 test.find( { "_id" : ObjectId("5879b0f65a56a454"), "a" : 1 })
```

you need to include curly braces in the round brackets like ({}) second thing enclose id in quotes, please refer the mongodb  manual

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Answer (score 1):

Something stupid I did that got me into this type of error, I would like to share here :

I was OUTSIDE of mongo shell and executing below command. I was using my smartphone and trying to update a record while I was travelling to my office via metro. I never felt for a minute that I was out of the shell unless I saw 'bash' and got to know how ignorant I was. By the way below is the query I was trying to execute with error :

karsh45:~/workspace $ db.users.updateOne({name:"dummyUser4"}, {$set:{email:"user4@gmail.com"}});
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `{name:"dummyUser4"},'

Answer (score 0):

If you cut and paste a possible error can be that your texteditor has changed the type of quotes. Took me a while to notice that the first " in front of Manhattan are the typografic kind.

```
db.clubs.update({clubname: ”Manhattan"}, {$push: {visitors: {women: 0}}})
```

The syntax is correct but those " give the error Unexpected Token